# How to perfect forward a member variable

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Consider the following code:

```cpp
template<typename T> void foo(T&& some_struct)
{
    bar(std::forward</* what to put here? */>(some_struct.member));
}
```

In the case of forwarding the whole struct I would do `std::forward<T>(some_struct)`. But how do I get the correct type when forwarding a member?

One idea I had was using `decltype(some_struct.member)`, but that seems to always yield the base type of that member (as defined in the struct definition).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Member access is [value category preserving](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ref#4.2). If the object expression is an lvalue, so is the member access, otherwise it is an xvalue (like the result of `std::move`). So do member access on the result of forwarding the object.

```
std::forward<T>(some_struct).member
```

Answer (score 14):

Member access does the right thing here: you just need `std::forward<T>(some_struct).member`.

Tested with:

```
template <class... >
struct check;

struct Foo {
    int i;
};

template <class T>
void bar(T &&f) {
    // fatal error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'check<int &&>'
    check<decltype((std::forward<T>(f).i))>{};
}

int main() {
    bar(Foo{42});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As explained by @StoryTeller, if you forward the struct then the member value catogory is preserved (I think this is important to keep in mind).
But how do I get the correct type when forwarding a member?
you could do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& some_struct) {
    bar(std::forward<decltype(std::declval<T>().member)>(some_struct.member));
}
```

In this code the actual object that's being forwarded is the member and not the object. 
As forwarding is a just conditional move, you might want to look at this two articles:
[enter link description here](http://oliora.github.io/2016/02/12/where-to-put-std-move.html)
[enter link description here](https://ldionne.com/2016/02/17/a-tentative-notion-of-move-independence/)

Comment: I like the two articles you linked. However, I don't really understand the point of the rest of the answer. It seems to contradict Louis Dionne's article, since if `member` is a reference, you'd be moving from the member when you probably should not do so.

Comment: @Justin You're absolutely right, you shouldn't, but if the member is not a shared object, moving it is perfectly safe( read the first arcticle). The snippet code is a possible solution to his question  " But how do I get the correct type when forwarding a member?". I linked the two articles to point to the asker, that doing so my not be safe.