# How to prefectly forward member variable of an r-value objects in variadic context

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, perfect-forwarding

While trying to optimize a library I wrote, I came across an issue that I cannot seem to solve.

Consider the wrapper struct below (simplified):

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct MyPair {
    T data;
    // some other stuff here
};
```

Perfectly forwarding a bunch of `MyPairs` is not an issue. But if I try to forward its member variable `data` for example into a tuple (could be others as well), it does not perfectly forward it but rather calls the move constructor instead:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
struct Tuple {
   public:
    template <typename... Pairs>
    Tuple(Pairs&&... pairs)
        : data_{std::forward<Ts>(pairs.data)...} {} // Not forwarding, calling move instead

   private:
    std::tuple<Ts...> data_;
};
```

The full working example can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GMo3n3rq3). The output indicates that a move constructor is called for each pair we will add.

I have tried other approaches such as forwarding the pair itself before accessing the member [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54709377/how-to-perfect-forward-a-member-variable)].
I have also tried alternatives but to no avail [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570655/perfect-forwarding-a-member-of-object)].

I would appreciate any help that allows us to get rid of unnecessary moves operations.

Comment: Perfect forwarding just means that the value category is forwarded. So a move is generally what you expect. There are sutiations where the move can be elided completely, but the requirements for when the compiler is allowed to do that kind of optimization is a different thing.

Comment: `std::forward<Pairs>(pairs).data` and watch the magic happen. Member access respects value category too (not by chance, it was designed with forwarding in mind).

Comment: Oh, I answered one of the Q&As you linked (and that say the same thing essentially). How did you "try" it? Because it's specified to work, and it will be more prudent to show how you did it (likely with a mistake) than describe yourself doing it and assuming it "just failed".

Comment: @super The thing that eludes me is that if I decide to store the whole instead of just `data`, I do not need any move at all. The value is perfectly forward with zero additional costs. The moment I decide to not store the whole Pair but just its value `data`, the compiler adds an additional move

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The issue is that `std::forward<Pairs>(pairs).data` is not really perfectly forwarding it. Instead, it will require a copy constructor to be called instead. As per your suggestion as to what I did, it was exactly trying this: `std::forward<Pairs>(pairs).data`. It makes the situation even worse since instead of a move, we now need to perform a [copy](https://godbolt.org/z/jME6dxb1P)

Comment: It performs a copy because the member is a reference (a detail that should be in a [mre] in the post itself, not in godbolt that was blocked on the network I accessed from before). https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.ref#6.sentence-1 - Reference members will always be forwarded as lvalues by standard machinery here. And there's no way to detect it's a member reference (decltype being the odd beast that it is).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thank you, that clarifies the ambiguity. Sorry for linking a godbolt example, will take care of that in the future. As such, I suppose that it is not possible to do it without a move

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I read through the specifications and understood my problem a bit better. What I was looking for is known as "destructive move". It has not been added to the language yet at the time of writing